# When can the local orientation of the sphere bundle piece together?

Tags: differential-geometry, algebraic-topology, homology-cohomology, vector-bundles, de-rham-cohomology

In Bott's "differential forms in algebraic topology", it is said that the orientation of a sphere bundle is equivalent to say there is an open cover $\{ U_\alpha\} $ on base space $M$ (we assume $M $ is a smooth manifold and the sphere bundle $E$ is $n$-dimensional) and generators $\{ [\sigma_\alpha]\in H^n(E|_{U_\alpha})\} $ such that $\ [\sigma_\alpha]=[\sigma_\beta]$ in $\ H^n(E|_{U_\alpha \cap U_\beta})$ and each generates the cohomology of the fiber when restricted on each fiber. Then the caveat in the book said the cohomology class  $\ [\sigma_\alpha]$ agree on the overlap doesn't mean they piece together to get a global cohomology class on $M$.
[image]

In fact, the context in the book then investigates the condition when it can piece to get a global cohomology class on $M$: the Euler class $\ e(E) \in H^{n+1}(M)$ vanishes.

But according to the Mayer-Vietoris sequence on the sphere bundle:
$$\ 0\to \Omega^*(E|_{U_{\alpha\cup\beta}}\space) \to  \Omega^*(E|_{U_{\alpha}}\space)\bigoplus\Omega^*(E|_{U_{\beta}}\space) \to\Omega^*(E|_{U_{\alpha\cap\beta}}\space)\to0$$
so there is a long exact sequence of cohomology:
$$...\to H^n(E|_{U_{\alpha\cup\beta}}\space) \to H^n(E|_{U_{\alpha}}\space)\bigoplus H^n(E|_{U_{\beta}}\space) \to H^n(E|_{U_{\alpha\cap\beta}}\space)\to H^{n+1}(E|_{U_{\alpha\cup\beta}}\space)\to...$$
We then put $\ [\sigma_\alpha]$ and$\ [\sigma_\beta]$ in$$\ H^n(E|_{U_{\alpha}}\space)\bigoplus H^n(E|_{U_{\beta}}\space) $$so if cohomology class  $\ [\sigma_\alpha]$ and$\ [\sigma_\beta]$ agree on the overlap, it means it lies in the kernal of the next map, so there must exist at least one cohomology class  $\ [\sigma_{\alpha\cup\beta}]$ when restricted on $\ U_\alpha$ and $\ U_\beta $ is $\ [\sigma_\alpha]$ and$\ [\sigma_\beta]$ respectively. So we piece together $\ [\sigma_\alpha]$ and $\ [\sigma_\beta]$ with no condition. In fact, if the manifold M is compact, we can repeat this procedure to get a global cohomology class on E. It means that we can always piece together them on a compact manifold. But the Euler class of a sphere bundle on a compact manifold is not always zero.

So my question is what's wrong in it? Besides, I found a similar argument in Spanier's *Algebraic Topology* (page 262), it said that the similar orientation class can always be pieced together. So what's the difference behind these two arguments? I'm really confusing. Thank you!
[image]

Comment: How nice! You are a new user but asked a question properly. It would be nicer if include images, rather than links.

Comment: Thank you! I try to add the picture, but it seems that new user can only upload a link? I'm not familiar with it now.

Comment: Should I do it?

Comment: Yes, sure, thank you!

Comment: The issue is that if we are covered by $U_{\alpha}, U_{\beta}, U_{\gamma}$ and you have picked a cohomology class on $U_{\alpha} \cup U_{\beta}$ I see no reason why the restriction of the class on $U_{\gamma}$ needs to restrict to the same class on $(U_{\alpha} \cup U_{\beta} ) \cap U_{\gamma}=(U_{\alpha} \cap U_{\gamma}) \cup (U_{\beta} \cap U_{\gamma})$.

Comment: Perhaps an extreme example will help (unrelated to sphere bundles): Suppose I have a nontrivial cohomology class $\gamma$ on $M$ and I take a cover by Euclidean open subsets $U_i$, then on every subset $U_i$, $\gamma =0$, but globally $\gamma \neq 0$.

Comment: Thank you very much! It really helps a lot. I am a new learner in algebraic topology, can I follow you? I am a new user and not familiar with this website.

Comment: I don’t think there is any following type of thing on this website, but if you click on my name you can see my past questions and answers. For future information, if you type @name it will alert them to your comment.